# Using distinct views for distinct devices ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewengine

I need to use distinct version of views, for each device.
For example:

Controller/Action: Home/Index

PC - Home.cshtml, Android - Home.Android.cshtml, iPad - Home.iPad.cshtml

These pages contains different markup, but each device. But how it can be activated and detected using ASP.NET MVC IOC?

Comment: For what reason do you need a different view for each device? Do stylesheets not suffice the purpose for the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Install MVC4 Developer Preview ;)

Comment: Reason is that markup is rather distinct in several devices.

Answer (score 1):

What are you looking for is **Mobile capable view engine**, look here :

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek10NewMobileViewEnginesForASPNETMVC3SpeccompatibleWithASPNETMVC4.aspx

Comment: Generally, your proposal is nice. But how it can be extended to several devices?